# Is it possible to have a php script read from column A and write the string in column B,C,E,etc in the same table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to plan ahead since I'm super new to PHP.

**I plan on doing a script that takes votes from multiple people, stores it in a database, a php script calculates the average, and writes it in a table. This is item specific meaning each (A) column row is different from the one below.**

This is my plan:

```
   // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT From DB (A);
```

The last part is where I get stuck. I want to have a menu ( scroball type of thing ) that the user can select a name from the column A. I know how to make a table/echo out of the input.

I've found this:

```
<form action ="register.php" name="myform" method = "POST">
    <select name="gender" id="gender">
            <option value="">Select One</option>
            <option value = "M">Male</option>
            <option value = "F">Female</option>
    </select>
</form>

$SQL = "INSERT INTO yourtable (gender) VALUES ('$gender')";

mysql_real_escape_string($sql);
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

From what I'm seeing, this script doesn't make a new row for the answer everytime a new one comes in. It just stores it in front of the original column since it can only have one answer.

---

If the first part success
Then, when the user inputs the number for column b in the form, mysql does this

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO DB (B)
VALUES ('Taken From Form B')";
```

and the php script will do the rest for calculating the average and outputting.

---

** I know I can insert directly into mysql but can it be repeated multiple times for the same item?**

Is this even possible?

Thanks for any help anyone might offer !

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this. It implies a fundamental design flaw. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet!

Comment: @Strawberry Then what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused, at least I get confused reading your question.
PHP(with the mysql) is a server side language and that does not respond to anything that is done in the browser unless you send the data back to the server.

PHP (server side) executes on the server what should be done and sends the result to the computer. That result will be something like HTML etc.

So if someone selects 'female' this should be send back to a file on the server first before it can be saved in mysql.

The rest is of course possible.

Comment: I thought PHP can take forms ( data ) and write to mysql directly?

`$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";`

Comment: Yes if it is POSTed to the server. It will happen in the server only.